# WPF application where a datagrid is presented in the same frame for multiple data set types

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Any examples of WPF application where a datagrid is presented in the same frame for different data types.  IE., the columns, datasource, for the datagrid change frequently based on other criteria?

Not sure if this should be implemented using a single view and datagrid or multiple views, and hiding the other non-used views?

J

Answer (score 0):

Yes using multiple `DataGrid`s and playing with their display should be the correct approach.

Depending on your needs you can use a `TabControl` with one `DataGrid` per `TabItem`.

Or multiple `Expander`s, one per `DataGrid`.